Is the projective sphere a finite projective plane?
I am working on an introductory project on projective planes. I'm aware of finite plains such as the order 2 and order 3 projective plane. Wikipedia mentions the complex projective plane as an example of an infinite projective plane.

Question: Is the projective sphere - where a "point" is defined as a pair of antipodal points on a sphere, and a "line" is a great circle between these antipodal points - an example of an infinite projective plane?

I figured a projective sphere would be a good way to visualize a possible infinite projective plane.
If it isn't, what are some other examples?

Yes, this is one (well-known) model for the real projective plane.

Since you mentioned Wikipedia's treatment of the complex projective plane, it is worth pointing out that there is also an article on the real projective plane, which addresses both of your questions. You might want to clarify if you're asking for further detail or some confusing part of that article...?

Yes, that is the equivalent of the real projective plane.

Little additional fun fact: the sphere (without identifying antipodal points) is a projective line.

Do you know what a field is? Given a field, $k,$ we can define an equivalence relation on $k^3\setminus{(0,0,0)}$ by making $(a,b,c)\sim (d,e,f)$ if there is an element $\lambda\in k^\times$ such that $(d,e,f)=(\lambda a,\lambda b,\lambda c).$ The quotient of this set with this relation is a projective plane. It is infinite if $k$ is infinite, so , for example, any field containing the rationals gives an example.

Thank you everyone, this has reminded me that I should read a lot more closely into these articles, not skimming.
